# Как сохранить стек с фрагментами при перезапуске активити?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

У меня имеется фрагмент, в котором я изменяю `delegate.localNightMode` родительского Activity. При изменении происходит полное пересоздание родительского Activity и, следовательно, полная очистка стека фрагментов в supportFragmentManager. Возможно ли как-нибудь сохранить стек фрагментов в данной ситуации, чтобы после смены темы вернуть всё к прежнему состоянию?